# gcc ODBC on Linux is not linking

Tags: c, linux, unixodbc

I am attempting to get up and running with some simple C odbc code (with a fairly simple utility in mind that I need for a larger application).  The problem is, I am so far unable to get my simple test case to compile and link into a binary that I can actually execute.

This code is from the easysoft website, and is about the simplest example they have available:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sql.h>
#include <sqlext.h>

main() {
  SQLHENV env;
  char driver[256];
  char attr[256];
  SQLSMALLINT driver_ret;
  SQLSMALLINT attr_ret;
  SQLUSMALLINT direction;
  SQLRETURN ret;

  SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &env);
  SQLSetEnvAttr(env, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (void *) SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0);

  direction = SQL_FETCH_FIRST;
  while(SQL_SUCCEEDED(ret = SQLDrivers(env, direction,
                       driver, sizeof(driver), &driver_ret,
                       attr, sizeof(attr), &attr_ret))) {
    direction = SQL_FETCH_NEXT;
    printf("%s - %s\n", driver, attr);
    if (ret == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) printf("\tdata truncation\n");
  }
}
```

My compile statement is: **gcc -lodbc listdrivers.c -o listdrivers**

Output from gcc:

```
/tmp/cchgAMyC.o: In function `main':
listdrivers.c:(.text+0x2f): undefined reference to `SQLAllocHandle'
listdrivers.c:(.text+0x4d): undefined reference to `SQLSetEnvAttr'
listdrivers.c:(.text+0xd8): undefined reference to `SQLDrivers'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I thought maybe it wasn't actually finding the library, so I specified the path on the command line:

**gcc -lodbc -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu listdrivers.c -o listdrivers**

Still no luck.  I also verified that the driver is installed and configured for use.

**ldconfig -p | grep odbc**

```
libodbcinstQ4.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbcinstQ4.so.1
libodbcinst.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbcinst.so.2
libodbcinst.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbcinst.so
libodbccr.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbccr.so.2
libodbccr.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbccr.so
libodbc.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbc.so.2
libodbc.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbc.so
libiodbcinst.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libiodbcinst.so.2
libiodbcadm.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libiodbcadm.so.2
libiodbc.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libiodbc.so.2
```

Then I thought maybe the library itself is corrupt, but that also looks fine:

**readelf -Ws /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbc.so | grep Alloc**

```
   113: 0000000000007870    21 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 SQLAllocStmt
   148: 0000000000007820    67 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 SQLAllocHandleStd
   164: 0000000000007810    10 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 SQLAllocHandle
   196: 0000000000006720    21 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 SQLAllocConnect
   213: 0000000000006740    20 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 SQLAllocEnv
```

The function is clearly listed in the library, and I see no reason why that library would not be getting included, but at this point, I am stuck...

I have also tried removing and reinstalling the unixodbc and unixodbc-dev packages to no avail.  Any help would be greatly appreciated as this is now driving me crazy.

Comment: A bit more information:  I am attempting to compile on an Ubuntu 15.05 system, but I also tried on Ubuntu 12.04 with the same results.  When I attempted this same build on a Fedora VM I had handy, I was able to build without any problems, and the generated binary works as expected...  So this appears to be specific at least to Ubuntu, but possibly other Debian based distros?

Answer (score 5):

So it turns out that on Ubuntu, the -lodbc needs to come after the c file.  So the following appears to work fine:

**gcc listdrivers.c -o listdrivers -lodbc**

I didn't realize the order would make any difference in this case, and on Fedora the order doesn't matter (possibly a different version of gcc, but I didn't check specifically)

Comment: Hi, tried this but mine is saying "undefined reference to symbol '_...' error adding symbols, DSO missing from the command line. Do you know how to solve this ?

Comment: awesome, putting the -lodbc after the c files worked for me